# Unclear to $rootScope.emit()?

Tags: angularjs

I know how to use on, emit and broadcast event in `$scope`.

In my opinion, use of `$rootScope` is mainly similar to $scope except `$rootScope.$emit` will fire an event for all `$rootScope.$on` listeners only, `$rootScope.$broadcast` will notify all `$rootScope.$on` as well as `$scope.$on` listeners.

However, I am confused to a tutorial code which only use `$rootScope.$on` through the entire project. This project allow users route to different page and use their cookie to ensure login status.

I do not find any clue where it calls `emit()` or `broadcast()` to trigger event from a listener. Does `emit()` or `broadcast()` fire in the project or it does not need it at all? Can anyone explain the login behind this phenomenon? In what cases, `$rootScope` does not need `emit()` or `broadcast()`?

Here is partial code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'HomeController',
                templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .when('/login', {
                controller: 'LoginController',
                templateUrl: 'login/login.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .when('/register', {
                controller: 'RegisterController',
                templateUrl: 'register/register.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
    }

    run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http'];
    function run($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
        // keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
        if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
        }

        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
            var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
            var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
            if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $locationChangeStart event is broadcasted on the $rootScope by angular itself (the $location service, to be precise): https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#$locationChangeStart